# How to understand sed with complex replace?

Tags: sed

For exmaple:

```
  sed 's@/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)\?/ld@/tools&@g' abc.txt
```

What are those meanings such as 's@' , '(' , '\?' ,'&' ,and '@' ?

How to find a proper and simplest way to learn sed?

abc.txt:

```
  #define GNU_USER_LINK_EMULATION32 "elf32%{EB:b}%{EL:l}tsmip"
  #define GNU_USER_LINK_EMULATION64 "elf64%{EB:b}%{EL:l}tsmip"
  #define GNU_USER_LINK_EMULATIONN32 "elf32%{EB:b}%{EL:l}tsmipn32"

  #define GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER32 "/lib/ld.so.1"
  #define GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER64 "/lib64/ld.so.1"
  #define GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32 "/lib32/ld.so.1"
  #define UCLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32 "/lib32/ld-uClibc.so.0"
  #define BIONIC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32 "/system/bin/linker32"
  #define GNU_USER_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32 \
    CHOOSE_DYNAMIC_LINKER (GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32, UCLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32, \
               BIONIC_DYNAMIC_LINKERN32)
```

Thank you~

Comment: what  relation does your abc.txt has with your question

Comment: I use it for the input of sed command.

Comment: Once you understand that command you will have learned 99% of what you need to know to use sed appropriately (the rest being use of \1, etc. backreferences). Don't bother with books, tutorials, etc. as they mostly just tell you how to use sed in-appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual is a good place to start http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Breaking down that specific command:

```
sed 's@/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)\?/ld@/tools&@g' abc.txt
```

The string in quotes `'s@/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)\?/ld@/tools&@g'` is a single argument command for sed to run, it is the 's' ('substitute') command  in this case http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

The separator used there is the @ symbol, so the regexp is `/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)\?/ld` and the replacement is `/tools&`. There is a 'g' option at the end, which applies to all matches within each line, not just the first.

For the regular expression, `\(` and `\)` delimit a capturing group, `\?` means "optionally match the previous atom (match zero or one times)" (the previous atom being that group). The rest of the characters are matched as is, so this means it would match `/lib/ld`, `/lib64/ld`, `/lib32/ld` or `/lib6432/ld`.

In the replacement, the `&` includes the whole match, so effectively it prefixes all of the matches with `/tools`.

Comment: I'm not quite understand why I can't ignore /ld ? ex. sed 's_/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)_/tools&_g' abc.txt   Why this cmd only match /lib32 ?

Comment: Because you have: `(64)\?` which means `64` or nothing, and `32` always. Are you using extended regexps? 

Maybe what you actually want then is:

`s,/lib\(32\|64\)\?/,/tools&,g`

Comment: +1 very complete answer. Some seds have a `-r` option that allow you to leave out the backslashes: `sed -r 's@/lib(64)?(32)?/ld@/tools&@g'`

Answer (score 2):

you need to learn REGEX first before learning sed or awk. they are mostly regex based . 
Start from here [REGEX](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl20.html)

Then you can start sed from here http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

The best way is learn by practice . After learning regex start looking at sed questions from SO and see how people are answering. Firstly try to solve yourself and then see the answer given